# How can I create high quality custom marker in android Google maps api?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, bitmap, google-maps-markers

I created custom marker in 25x26 px. The problem is, when the marker displayed in maps it give me a low quality image. When I resize the picture in 250x260 px (I draw in inkscape again) it gives me the high quality picture, but it to take a big amounts of screen to load. How can I create the small custom marker with high quality image?